# Python: running a thread in a class method

Tags: python, multithreading

Hello :) How can I run a thread in a class method? For example:

```
val = ""

def func2():
    while True:
        #reading from some stream and writing into val

class MyClass:

    def func1(self):
        while True:
            #do some work
            if val == "xyz":
                #do some work
                val = ""
```

I need to run func1 and func2 simultaneously. func1 is reading data from some stream and write it to global varaible val and func2 is doing some work and reading val. I wanted to run func2 in func1 in a different thread. How can I do that?

Comment: This is not a problem with your code but a lack of research. Read the docs as told by Sinapse or the chapters about multithreading in Mark Lutz book "Programming python" or another you like more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about reading these docs?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html